# How I can merge multiplicate queries which return multiple columns in a procedure?

Tags: mysql, procedure

I've 2 tables calls patients and events

```
---------         ----------
| users |         | events |
---------         ----------
|user_id|         |event_id|
|team_id|  1 -n   |user_id | 
|  .... |         | ....   | 
---------         ----------
```

I want to create a procedure to return the user name and their event's name

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getAll(user_id INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE id_user INT;
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE user CURSOR FOR SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE team_id = id_team;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN usuarios;
  update_loop: LOOP
    FETCH user INTO id_patient;

    IF done THEN
        LEAVE update_loop;
    END IF;

    SELECT name FROM users WHERE user_id = id_user;
    SELECT nameE FROM events WHERE user_id = id_user LIMIT 0,2;
  END LOOP;
END
```

I want to list the name and next, the name of their event to send a JSON to back. How can i do ? Temporary table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need use a `cursor`,try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getAll $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getAll(user_id INT)
BEGIN


SELECT u.user_id,u.name,e.ename FROM users u
INNER JOIN events e ON e.user_id = u.id_user
WHERE u.id_user = user_id ;

 END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Solution Events grouped by user:

```
DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getAll $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE getAll(user_id INT)
    BEGIN


    SELECT user_id,u.name,GROUP_CONCAT(e.ename SEPARATOR ',')  FROM users u
    INNER JOIN events e ON e.user_id = u.id_user
    WHERE u.id_user = user_id 
    GROUP BY u.id_user;

     END $$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This query only return one event.

Comment: Should return all events that match the user id passed by parameter.

Comment: What is the correct parameter ´team_id´ or ´user_id´?

Comment: Return all events thats correct, but each row has the user name and event name. I want user name only once time and all the events name.

Comment: If so, a possible solution would be to return the user with all their events separated by commas in another column?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `Procedure`. Just a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT users.name, events.Ename from users, events 
    WHERE users.user_id=events.user_id 
          AND users.user_id = 52823;
```

And `52823` is the desired `user_id` of course.

But it is nevertheless possible to put it in a procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getAll(in user_id INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT users.name, events.Ename from users, events 
        WHERE users.user_id=events.user_id 
              AND users.user_id = user_id;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Full join return cartesian product

Comment: Sorry, isn't that what you wanted? A result of the form `(users.name, events.Ename)` such that there are zero to many `events.Ename` for each `users.name`? What is the problem with a cartesian product? If that's not what you are looking for gives us a more details of your desired resulting table (which tuple?).